# Using Proxy with wrapper objects around primitives

Tags: javascript, primitive

I want to use javascript's `Proxy` objects to augment a data structure with a bit of additional logging. While doing so, I noticed a problem:

```
simpleProxy = new Proxy(new Number(4), {})
simpleProxy.valueOf(); // TypeError: valueOf method called on incompatible Proxy
```

The error makes sense to me. `valueOf` is invoked with the `this` object set to the `Proxy` instead of the `Number` object thus leading to a type error.

The problem to me now is that in user code it is actually useful to propagate the `Proxy` as the `this` value into function calls so that access to properties is done through the proxy. Only when calling "low-level" routines like the above do I get in trouble. The question: How can I reliably detect that I'd be calling such a Proxy incompatible function, possibly assuming for a moment that user defined functions are safe to call?

---

This is not asking if the called function is a native function. Only certain native functions can not handle `Proxy` values. Besides, the detection in the linked question is rather unsound and would require different special cases here. Consider a function linked from a native interface. It may very well be able to operate on a proxy value, thus detecting it as a native function would be a false positive.

Currently, I believe the best approach is to find out if the `target` in `get` is primitive by calling `target.valueOf()` first instead of infering anything from whether the function is native or not. As such, this is not a duplicate.

Comment: I don't get an Incompatible Proxy Error. What browser are you using?

Comment: @zfrisch Firefox 58.0

Comment: Just tested this in Chrome 64.0 with an equivalent result.

Comment: Right, I was getting a similar error, but just wanted to make sure that it was the same type.

Answer (score 1):

First we check if the Property is from the prototype or from the target itself, if not and the key is that of a method, we return an anonymous function that passes its arguments into the method with the appropriate `this` when called.

Note: I'm not entirely sure if this is foolproof.

```js
let a = new Proxy(new Number(3), {
  get(target, key) {
    if (!target.hasOwnProperty(key) && typeof target[key] === "function") {
      return function(...args) {
        return target[key].call(target, args);
      }
    }
    return target[key];
  }
});

console.log( a.valueOf() );
```

Comment: I have researched a bit. Builtin functions are a problem, specifically because they specify thing like [thisNumberValue](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-thisnumbervalue) that accesses internal slots. All user code must call `valueOf` or use one of the builtin methods, anyway. I think what I'll do is special case all of these internal methods, even if it's not pretty. Your solution catches a bit too much, for example inherited methods.